# How can I understand the logic of Fast Point Feature Histograms (FPFH) descriptor?

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, mesh, sampling

I have been using FPFH features quite a lot in global registration and key-point extraction a lot, I also looked [pcl](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/fpfh_estimation.html) page that *tries* to explain what it is, but fails to give detail to reader in my opinion. I have a general understanding of what it is, but for example I have no idea why it has 33 dims, but not 34? In short, I want to understand in detail.